# Why in C, on MacOS Sierra, this program alter the integer values of the array?

Tags: c

This program converts hexadecimal characters to base64. In the first part of the program, the hexadecimal input given is converted to integers and are saved in an integer array. I print the decimal values to be sure. Then when base64 conversion starts, for unknown reason, some of the values of the integer array are altered. Why does this happen? Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc != 2)
        return 0;

    int lengthArgvOne = strlen(argv[1]);

    /* Control variables */
    unsigned short int i, j, k, moduleArgv;

    char *oneHexaArgvChar = argv[1];
    char *hexaCharset = "0123456789abcdef";
    char *base64Charset = "ABDCEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
    int decimalElements = (lengthArgvOne / 2);
    unsigned short int *boxOfNumbers = (unsigned short int*)malloc(decimalElements);

    if(((lengthArgvOne % 3) == 2) || ((lengthArgvOne % 3) == 1))
        moduleArgv = 1;
    else
        moduleArgv = 0;

    int base64Elements = (((lengthArgvOne / 3) * 4) + (moduleArgv * 4));
    unsigned char *decimalConverted = (unsigned char*)malloc(base64Elements);

    /* Number of base64 sextets to represent argv [1] */
    if (((lengthArgvOne % 3) == 2) || ((lengthArgvOne % 3 ) == 1))
        i = 1;
    else
        i = 0;

    struct {
        unsigned int eightBits : 0x8;     
        unsigned int sixBits   : 0x6;     
    } chunksOfByte; 

    /* -----------------argv[1] Input data processing and control.----------------- */
    /* Conversion from uppercase(A,B,C,D,E y F) to lowercase (a, b, c, d, e and f)  */
    /* It is corroborated that the characters in argv [1] are hexa.                 */
    /* Conversion from hex to decimal. The decimal is stored in boxOfNumbers        */
    for (i = 0, j = 0,k = 0; i < lengthArgvOne; i++) {
                 if ((*(oneHexaArgvChar + i) > 64) && (*(oneHexaArgvChar + i) < 71)) {
            *(oneHexaArgvChar + i) = (*(oneHexaArgvChar + i) + 32);
        }
        /*------------*/
        while(*(oneHexaArgvChar + i) != *(hexaCharset + j)){
            j++;
            if (j == 16)
                return 0;
        } 
        /*------------*/
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            chunksOfByte.eightBits = j << 4;
        } else {
            boxOfNumbers[k++] = (chunksOfByte.eightBits + j);
        }
        j = 0;
    }

    /* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
    for (i = 0; i < decimalElements; i++)
        printf("Element %d before convertion proces to base64 : %d\n", i, boxOfNumbers[i]); 
    /* ---------------------Convertion decimal to base64----------------------- */
    for (i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; i < decimalElements; i++) {
        printf("Element %d INSIDE: %d\n", i, boxOfNumbers[i]); 
        if (j == 0) {
            decimalConverted[k++] = *(base64Charset + (boxOfNumbers[i] >> 2));
            chunksOfByte.sixBits = (boxOfNumbers[i] << 4);
            if (((decimalElements % 3) == 1) && (i == (decimalElements -1))) {
                decimalConverted[k++] = *(base64Charset + chunksOfByte.sixBits);
                decimalConverted[k++] = '=';
                decimalConverted[k] = '=';
            }
        }
        if (j == 1) {
             decimalConverted[k++] = *(base64Charset + (chunksOfByte.sixBits | (boxOfNumbers[i] >> 4)));
             chunksOfByte.sixBits = boxOfNumbers[i] << 2;
             if (((decimalElements % 3) == 2) && (i == (decimalElements - 1))) {
                 decimalConverted[k++] = *(base64Charset + chunksOfByte.sixBits);
                 decimalConverted[k] = '=';
             }
         }
         if (j == 2) {
             decimalConverted[k++] = *(base64Charset + (chunksOfByte.sixBits | (boxOfNumbers[i] >> 6)));
             chunksOfByte.sixBits = boxOfNumbers[i];
             decimalConverted[k++] = *(base64Charset + chunksOfByte.sixBits);
         }

         (j == 2) ? (j = 0) : j++;
     }

     printf("Base64: %s\n", decimalConverted);

     return 0;
}
```

OS: MacOS Sierra - 16GB RAM - i5

Compilation method: **gcc -g -Wall -o limpio limpio.c**

Output example:

**./limpio 49276d206b696c6c69**

```
Element 0 before convertion proces to base64 : 73
Element 1 before convertion proces to base64 : 39
Element 2 before convertion proces to base64 : 109
Element 3 before convertion proces to base64 : 32
Element 4 before convertion proces to : 107
Element 5 before convertion proces to : 105
Element 6 before convertion proces to : 108
Element 7 before convertion proces to : 108
Element 8 before convertion proces to : 105 // ⬅️ORIGINAL VALUE
Element 0 INSIDE: 73
Element 1 INSIDE: 39
Element 2 INSIDE: 109
Element 3 INSIDE: 32
Element 4 INSIDE: 107
Element 5 INSIDE: 105
Element 6 INSIDE: 108
Element 7 INSIDE: 108
Element 8 INSIDE: 21331 // ⬅️¿WHY DOES THIS CHANGE? ALTERED VALUE
Base64: SSdtIGtpbG
```

Comment: I think you should look at the `isxdigit()` function (macro) from `<ctypes.h>`, and you should think about writing a hex-to-decimal conversion function.  Consider using `sscanf(…, "%2X", …)` for converting from hex characters.  (Checking that the characters are hex is probably a good idea; `sscanf()` would convert a single hex digit if the second character was not a hex digit.

Comment: If short is 2 bytes then you're writing twice as many bytes as you allocated.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding the purpose of the structure with two bit fields in it (variable `chunksOfByte`).  I'm wondering if that's supposed to be a `union`, but using a `union` is fraught too — actually, bit fields are almost always fraught.  However, if it is any consolation, I can reproduce the problem, down to the 21331 value, on my Mac running Sierra, and I'm using GCC 6.3.0 instead of XCode, so it is going to something reasonably generic when it is found.  On the face of it, the likely problem is an array bounds violation.  But I'm still working on it.

Comment: the posted code contains dozens of 'implicit conversions.  You might want to 1) enable warnings when compiling and 2) fix those warnings.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc), 1) the returned type is `void*` so can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding these two lines:  `if (argc != 2)
        return 0;`  1) when the wrong command line argument count is used, it is best to output a message to `stderr` that is a 'usage' statement. Then exit with some kind of error indication (0 means success)  for instance: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s string\n", argv[0] );  followed by: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`   Note: `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are both found in the header `stdlib.h`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) define data/structs/etc before `main()` and then only declare an instance of the data inside `main()`

Comment: @RamiroDuttoLuquez,  No warnings!!!  Really,  I don't know what compiler your using,  However, on linux, for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu11`  will output 16 warnings.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll put them into practice.

Comment: the posted code uses several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 2, 3, 4, 16, 32, 64, 71.  'magic' numbers make the code very difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement of `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: @uaer3629249, I was compiling only with `-Wall -Wextra -std=c11`. WARNINGS appeared with `-Wconversion`

Comment: you might want to look into the header file: `ctype.h`  which contains such items as `toupper()`, `tolower()`, `isdigit()`, `ishex()`, `isalpha()`

Comment: in general, such a conversion would be performed by:  `result = strtoll( argv[1], 64 );`

Comment: @user3629249: Your `strtoll()` call is missing the end pointer, and the base should be 0 or 2..36.  In context, I believe you're after base 16 — but the code is also doing the conversion by pairs of hex digits.  So, while a lot of your advice has been good, I think the `strtoll()` suggestion is way off-base.

Comment: As @immibis pointed out so tersely as to be inscrutable, you have `unsigned short int *boxOfNumbers = (unsigned short int*)malloc(decimalElements);` which is allocating half the space you need.  Multiply the size by `sizeof(*boxOfNumbers)`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler,  Your correct,  I just tossed that comment about strtoll() in without thinking about it first.

Answer (score -2):

The solution.

[SOLUTION](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66325/por-qu%c3%a9-en-c-el-desplazamiento-de-bits-de-un-elemento-de-una-array-de-enteros?noredirect=1#comment121790_66325).

Thanks @OscarGarcia and everibody who expended time analizing this code.